# Windows service using TopShelf: The underlying provider failed on Open. User logon failure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, topshelf

My project is a window service create by TopShelf. It store data in local database but a error occurre:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. > System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: User logon failure 'USER'

My string connection is:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ValeQpsContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=Vale.Qps;Integrated Security=False;
         User Id=USER; Password=xxxx" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

My database is a local db using SQL EXPRESS and my service run as local system.

This is method for store data in database:

```
public static void Insert<T>(T entity)
            where T : class
        {
            try
            {
                using (var ctx = new MyContext())
                {
                    ctx.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;

                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

This is a complete inner exception:

> The underlying provider failed on Open. System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. > System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: User logon failure 'USER'. em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<>c.b__13_0 em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open em System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.b__55_0 em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0 em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute em System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open

The same permissions (USER and password) are define in SSMS to database. Where is error?

Comment: Why do you think this error is related to TopShelf? What happens if you run the app as if it were a console app? Does it still get the same error? Seems like you have a more general SQL Server connectivity/authentication issue that has nothing to do with TopShelf.

Comment: If I to use Ctrl+F5 in VS 2019 the service run normally and not throw this exception but when service is installed occurred.

Comment: Don't run it through Visual Studio. Go to the location where it's installed, and run the executable from there. What happens?

Comment: The same exception.

Comment: Therefore it's not an issue with TopShelf. Did you verify that the .exe.config that ends up in the installation directory has the correct username/password? Do you perhaps have config transforms that apply to Debug builds but not Release builds, or vice versa?

Comment: App.exe.config is ok. I am add AttachDBFilename='path\mydb.mdf' and Integrated Security=SSPI. It's ok when execute my .exe from executable folder (Release or Debug builded), but when installed service i not have permissions: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. > System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: CREATE DATABASE permission denied on database 'master'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. I changed my connection string to:

```
  <connectionStrings><add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS01\MSSQL\DATA\MyDatabase.mdf;User Id=DOMAIN\USER; Password=xxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

And i also change commands to install service. Added logon user:

```
MyService.exe install -username:DOMAIN\USER -password:xxxx start
```

So, this is not exacly error, but is ok now.